# how can we print http flow of a browser with python? [Like browser network tab]

Tags: python, networking, tcp, proxies, httpinterceptor

In Python i want to build a program like browser network tab, which prints all http/s flows. The same thing needs to be done with python.

[#urllib #requests #basicHTTPRequest etc..] modules are there but how can i get the network traffic of a browser?

1. can we achieve that by binding socket to proxy of a browser?

   ```
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
   sock.listen(1)
   self._sockets.append(sock)
   ```
2. Need to create a tcp connection over that address and port of a proxy?

suggest me a good resource to achieve.